# Greek text does not compile

Tags: greek

Hello everyone and congratulations for your nice job here on this site.

I'm a new LaTeX user and mainly writing in Greek language. I'm using `xgreek` package along with `xltxtra`, in order to take advantage of my system's fonts. So far I can successfully use various templates I found on this site (and write in Greek), but sometimes greek text does not compile at all (process exits normally but with no Greek text). For example I'm trying to put some greek text in this (beautifull) template https://www.overleaf.com/14591552cycdsbpgvgjd#/55841579/ but nothing happens. What I changed in this template is that I added `\usepackage{xltxtra}` and `\usepackage{xgreek}` and also inserted just one Greek word in main text. The Greek word does not appear. What am I missing?

I know that is a very generalised question but what I'm trying to find is if there is a general guidance I have to follow before I'll be more specific.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please add a small example of the code you're using?

Comment: the log file probably shows "missing character" warnings, that template has `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{cmss}` so uses computer modern sans serif which has no greek (and isn't a suitable font encoding for xelatex)

Comment: egreg thanks for your reply. I just don't know how to put the code here. As I describe in my question , I just added two commands and a Greek word in the links template. Nothing more.

Comment: Mr Carlisle thanks for your reply. I'll try to change the font family to a suitable one. Any suggestion?

Comment: @AlexM Just copy from Overeaf and paste here; select the pasted code and click on the `{}` icon at the top of the editing box. Note that loading `xltxtra` is not needed and actually no longer recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try to remove the `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{cmss}` in line 16
and just add in preamble the following

```
\usepackage{xltxtra} 
\usepackage{xgreek} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\setromanfont{FreeSerif}
\setsansfont{FreeSans}
```